# width based if else toggle in js

Tags: javascript, css

I might just be dumb but I can't seem to get some javascript code working

```
function toggleNav() {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('side-bar');
  var back = document.getElementById('backspace');

  if (sidebar.style.width === "0") {
    sidebar.style.width = "400px";
    back.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    back.style.right = "0";
  } else {
    sidebar.style.width = "0";
    back.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    back.style.right = "-50px";
  }
}
```

I'm trying to check the width of this element, then if it's 0px in width it expands using a CSS transition and the back id is the button that is toggling everything

Comment: maybe `(sidebar.style.width == '0px')`? just something to try. can you `console.log(sidebar.style.width)`?

Comment: what is `back.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";` doing?

Comment: no, I can't do console.log(sidebar.style.width)

Comment: back.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"; is rotating an arrow

Comment: as you wrote it i think it does nothing

Comment: How about using `sidebar.offsetWidth == 0`, does that work for you?

Comment: thanks ewizard for the help

Comment: i got it to work

Answer (score 1):

`if (sidebar.style.width === "0")` should be `if (sidebar.style.width == "0px")`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work after changing  if (sidebar.style.width === "0") to  if (sidebar.style.width === "0px") i see my error